# MSAL redirection has wrong URI

Tags: javascript, react-router, azure-ad-msal

I have set redirectUri both in the azure app and in the MSAL client code config. I'm able to log in but the problem is that microsoft redirects the browser to the wrong place.

This is the client code:

```
const options = {
redirectUri: "https://example.com/folder/#/private"
};
const client = new UserAgentApplication(appId, null, callback, options);
x.loginRedirect(scopes);
```

This is the expected redirectUri:

```
https://example.com/folder/#/private?token_id=12345
```

This is the actual redirectUri:

```
https://example.com/folder/#token_id=12345
```

Which totally break the app's router.

Is there a way to set MSAL so it follows the provided Uri and it uses query instead of hash for the token?

Comment: I've only see Azure AD redirectURI return the id token as a hash.  You're using a has in your url `folder/#/private?...` because you're using a single page application?  Can you use a url RewriteEngine or equivalent on you server to allow single page applications.  Also, have you thought about creating a separate redirectURI html page to handle the redirect from Azure AD?  This separate redirectURI page does not include your single page application.

Comment: See the following url. `zamzowd` comment on Mar 15 explains more. https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/585